# Trigger event when a user enters text and hits enter, or clicks an item from a data list

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have an input field for users to enter multiple emails, and a list of previously used emails that appear in a data list. I want to call the onNewToEmailAdded() method every time a user either enters text in the box and hits enter, or selects a value from the data list. How can I do that (I'm using Angular 2). At the moment the method is only called if the enter key is hit once an item has been selected from the list.

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="nweEmail" (keyup.enter)="onNewToEmailAdded()" 
     list="toEmailsList" />
<datalist id="toEmailsList">
   <option *ngFor="let email of previousToEmails">{{email}}</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to lack of events on datalist, you cannot trigger directly the event when an email is clicked on your list, thus your solution only working on enter key pressed after selection. But you still can use a workaround by using the (input) event on the input element like:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" (input)="compareInput($event.target.value) "[(ngModel)]="nweEmail" (keyup.enter)="onNewToEmailAdded()" 
     list="toEmailsList" />
<datalist id="toEmailsList">
   <option *ngFor="let email of previousToEmails">{{email}}</option>
</datalist>
```

This event will be triggered each time something changes on the input field, returning the value on the field at that point. From there you compare the value returned against your list of previousToEmails and if is a match you do what you wanted to do if an element on datalist was clicked.

```
compareInput(value) {
//if value is in the list do something
}
```

Keep in mind also that by doing this, when the user types an email that is on the previousList without selecting it, once it reaches the last character the event will trigger as it was selected which can lead to strange behavior for the user.